# Is there any way to control ls output format

Tags: ls, execute-command, output

I have a directory contains some svg images among its contents. I list them with following `ls` command to save the output in a file:

```
ls *200px.svg > animList.js
```

The output file looks like:

```
file1-200px.svg
file2-200px.svg
file3-200px.svg
...
fileX-200px.svg
```

I need the file name to be written like `'fileX-200px.svg',` to easily make this files list working like JavaScript array. i.e. I need the output file to be:

```
'file1-200px.svg',
'file2-200px.svg',
'file3-200px.svg',
...
'fileX-200px.svg',
```

So at the end I just need to add something like `var arr = [` at the beginning of the file and then add `];` at the end of the file to work as JavaScript array. **Is there any way in Linux to control the output display of the `ls` command?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although you *can* alter the formatting of `ls` output to some extent, for example

```
LC_CTYPE=C ls --quoting-style=locale *200px.svg
```

for single-quotes (see `info coreutils ls 'formatting the file names'` for details) it would be simpler just pass the results of the glob to the shell's `printf` function:

```
printf "'%s',\n" *200px.svg
```

Comment: Wow! It means that `printf` is an abbreviation for `print files`!

Comment: @SaidbakR it's more likely *print formatted* I think

Comment: +1 Or `find`’s `-printf` action to avoid possible maximum arguments limitt.

Comment: @Raffa I think that shouldn't be necessary so long as you're using the shell's built-in `printf` - see for example [Shell builtin `printf` line limit?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/519789/shell-builtin-printf-line-limit)

Comment: Got it :-) thanks … One wold have to exhaust all system memory resources accessible by this shell instance  in order to reach a limit … Still a distant possibility but could happen … Thanks again … I didn’t know this before.

Comment: @steeldriver but here it does not **only** format an input to it, it searches for files and listing them as well. However, what you have said about the abbreviation of *f* is true. It is about **f**ormat.

Comment: @SaidbakR It doesn’t search … the shell glob character `*` is expanded by the shell to matching filenames that are then passed to `printf` which only formats and prints what it sees.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to the accepted answer, we can [group three printf](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/combine-linux-commands) commands to generate complete JavaScript array file without the need to manual editing:

```
(printf "var arr =[\n" && printf "'%s',\n" *.svg && printf "];") >animList.js
```

I placed the above command in an executable `listing.sh` file in the same directory for easier call later:

```
#!/bin/bash
(printf "var arr =[\n" && printf "'%s',\n" *.svg && printf "];") >animList.js
echo "Done!"
```

#### Notice:

> **This is not an answer**. It is only an addition to optimize the value of the question's solution in a practical aspect.